# iPhone Tabbar controller - Itunes clone

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I am creating an app with 5 tab bars, like the iTunes app. In the iTunes app, when you click the tab that is already active then this tab is reloaded. This is not the standard behaviour of a tab bar controller, which seems to do nothing in this case. I cant find anything documented about this. Is it possible? Do I need to make a sub class of the controller?

Thanks in advance,
Eds

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `UITabbarControllerDelegate` and reload tabs on demand in `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` method.